# Why do I receive an ImortError with what seems to be a valid packaging structure?

Tags: python, importerror, python-packaging

Any ideas why python is not finding the `app` module I have defined in this project? I am trying to run `plant.py` and receiving "Module Not Found". I tried using relative import as well and received "ImportError: *attempted relative import with no known parent package*".

My project structure is:

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   └── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   └── v1
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── __pycache__
│   │       │   └── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │       ├── console.py
│   │       ├── dependencies.py
│   │       └── endpoints
│   │           ├── __init__.py
│   │           ├── __pycache__
│   │           └── plant.py
```

and the imports look like:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Query
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from sqlmodel import select
from app.api.v1.dependencies import get_db
from app.db.connector import init_db
from app.models import Health, Plant, PlantCreate, PlantRead

"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ethancloin/Developer/VSCodeProjects/PlantDaddyBackend/app/api/v1/endpoints/plant.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app.api.v1.dependencies import get_db
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
"""
```

I appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to run plant.py

You can't run `plant.py` directly (e.g. `python plant.py`) if it's in a package like that, because then the Python import machinery assumes `app` is in the same directory (and as you found out, you get an import error). Similarly, relative imports won't work because Python doesn't "know" `plant.py` is in a package; it expects it to be just a script.

You can use the ["run module" (`-m`) option](https://docs.python.org/3.10/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) instead from the directory where `app` is:

```
python -m app.api.v1.endpoints.plant
```